# I'm having issued with forms and form-actions. I'm trying to enter an image URL into a box, then see the image on page

Tags: php, html, image, forms

I have tried of few things, but this is just on the edge of what I understand, so I am grasping at straws of the advice I find online. I feel like I am missing some vital step or something, but I just don't know what it is. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php
  if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
  {
    $varImage = $_POST['formStuff'];
  }
?>
<form action="welcome.php" method="get">
  Image URL: <input type="text" name="stuff"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
Image Shown:<br><br> <?php echo $_GET["stuff"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is welcome.php:

```
<html>
<body>

Image Shown: <br><br><?php echo $_GET["stuff"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Once this is figured out, I plan on figuring out how to make the image the background instead of just an image. Shrug.

Answer (score 0):

try this in welcome.php

```
    <html>
    <body>
      <?php if(isset($_GET['stuff'])) { ?>
      Image Shown: <br><br><img src="<?php echo $_GET['stuff']; ?>"/>
      <?php } ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It still isn't working, although now i get an empty img, so thats improved.

Comment: I hope that we are talking about welcome.php
You can check the value of src in source of welcome.php

Comment: all i see when i look at the source is what i put in there, the php code. or am i confused what you are getting at?

Comment: If you are seeing the php code. Could it be possibly that your appache server is not running.

Comment: How do i make that run?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your url in  tag :
Like that way :

```
<img src="<?php echo $_GET['stuff']; ?>"/>
```